# The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers should follow the instructions here:

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, firebase-admob

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): Process: com.example.truthfxac, PID: 11877
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
E/AndroidRuntime(11877): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzi.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.4.0:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
E/AndroidRuntime(11877):    ... 10 more

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.name">
<!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Truthfx Academy"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="jhhjjhkjkjkjhkjkjjhkjhkjhkjhkjkj"/>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code into your manifest

```
<application
    ...>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>

</application>
```

and your string.xml would be like this

```
<string name="app_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy</string>
```

replace this id ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy with your original app id

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly. Feel so stupid. Simple thing like this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="jhhjjhkjkjkjhkjkjjhkjhkjhkjhkjkj"/>` 
With  this

```
<!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

If you are using real ads in app use your app id instead

Comment: thank  i supposed to add  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/> to my manifest in the app->src->androidmanifest but i was adding it to android manifest in the profile

Answer (score 0):

**Add the meta-data in your manifest like below with admobe application id inside in your application tag**

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-2046241422238764~3503622393" />


//ca-app-pub-2046241422238764~3503622393 this your Admobe app id
```